# Add unique identifer to model on create, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am forced to avoid default id for some actions.

I have model Advertisement.I added new column called **identifier**. Now I want to add unique random integer sequence when I create new advertisement.

So far I came up with this solution :

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base

   before_create :add_identifier

      def add_identifier      
        identifier = ('0'..'9').to_a.shuffle.first(5).join    
      end
end
```

This far it just creates random 5 digits long number. But how can check if any advertisements created before have this number already ? And how to insert it in databese while created ?

Or better solution would be in controller under Create action ?

Thanks

Comment: why not just use uuid https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code will retry up to 5 times to generate a id that's not already taken. You'll probably want to add a uniqueness validation (and a unique index constraint in the DB) for your identifier attribute. Also, take a look at the [SecureRandom](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) ruby module for generating random identifiers.

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :add_identifier

  def add_identifier
    retries = 0
    loop do
      self.identifier = ('0'..'9').to_a.shuffle.first(5).join
      retries += 1
      break if retries == 5 || !self.class.find_by(identifier: self.identifier)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: thanks, but when I added uniquenes validation I always got identifier taken. When I removed that validation and tried again I got 2 different identifiers. What could be the problem?

Comment: The validation happens before the `before_create` callback gets executed. So, at that point, the identifier is still `nil`. If there's already an `Advertisement` stored in the DB with a `nil` identifier, the uniqueness validation won't pass. If you know for sure you want every object to be created with an identifier, you'll have to change `before_create :add_identifier` to `before_validation :add_identifier`, and in the `add_identifier` method only set the identifier only if it's `blank?`. The `before_validation` callback will get executed before running your model validations.